# Getting 403 forbidden for POST Request

Tags: python, rest, api, python-requests

I need post some binary file to server by REST API. I'm using python requests lib for that. First of all I open the session for get cookies, and then execute POST request, but got 403 error.

```
import requests
url0 = "https://someUrl/api/v1"
url1 = "https://someUrl/api/v1/Action()"
headers = {
    'X-CSRF-Token': "E8D648268586298FBB52900F85C13CDC",
    'Authorization': "Basic User:Password_InBase64"
    }
s = requests.Session()
responce = s.get(url0, headers=headers)
print("first request")
print(responce.status_code)
headers = {
    'X-CSRF-Token': "E8D648268586298FBB52900F85C13CDC",
    }
payload = "{\"BinaryFile\": \"fileInBinary\"}"
response = s.post(url1, data=payload, headers=headers )
print("second request")
print(response.status_code)
print(response.headers)
```

In response with 403 error I see no information, why the error has occurred. The console output you can see below

```
first request
200
second request
403
{'X-CSRF-Token': 'Required', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
     'Content-Language': 'en', 'Content-Length': '762', 'Date': 'Tue, 14 Aug 
    2018 10:43:13 GMT', 'Server': 'SAP', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-
    age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload'}
```

Comment: You should ask the provider of the API for documentation. It is BTW no wonder that the GET requests works. CSRF tokens are mostly needed for changing actions.

Answer (score 0):

Check with API provider which methods (POST,GET) allowed.
Also if there are any IP restrictions on the 2nd endpoint (url1).

I recommend to work with PostMan of any similar application to make the requests - when all is working you can always see the how it looks in code.